# Can I use multiple file storage accounts from a single asp.net mvc app in Azure?

Tags: azure, storage, account

In Azure I have 2 load balanced VMs with an IIS shared config. These are linked to a premium storage account. All up and running. I have persisted the premium fileshare to both VMs as a drive (S).
The wwwroot is on the storage account, along with the IIS config files.
The app pool is set up as the storage account password so I have access the the share.
All good up to this point.

My issue is that the app also needs to see data on another fileshare. (general fileshare, not premium). This will be used for storage and Archive.

The problem is that the IIS app pool is configured with the creds for the premium storage and fails when trying to also use the general storage.

Can this be done?

Is there a way to link to both fileshares in IIS or should I be looking somewhere else?

Thanks

Colin